# Invertibility of a linear mapping of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand what should be a simple point in this question: [Inverse function theorem for matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291424/inverse-function-theorem-for-matrices).

Let $A$ be some matrix, and $L(H)$ be some linear function of $H$ (a matrix) with coefficients being powers of $A$. Since we do not have commutativity, $L(H)$ might equal, say, $AH+HA$.

The question is, when is this mapping invertible? According to the answer to the question above, it should only happen when the only solution to $AH+HA=0$ is $H=0$.

Why is this equivalent to being invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you have stated can be rewritten as $\ker(L) = \{0\}$, ie $L$ is injective. If the domain and the range of $L$ have the same (finite) dimension, then this implies that $L$ is also surjective, and thus invertible.

Obviously if you are in an infinite-dimensional space this no longer applies, but since you were speaking of matrices there shouldn't be problems.